# Swift iOS: Getting Cell's IndexPath From Custom Cell Class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to get the cell indexPath from within the cell's custom class.

When I put it this way:

```
let indexPath :NSIndexPath = (self.superview!.superview as! UITableView).indexPath(for: self)! as NSIndexPath
```

It works fine on iOS 10 device, but on iOS 11 simulator, it gives this error

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10636c5d8) to 'UITableView'
```

So, then when I change it and put it this way:

```
let indexPath :NSIndexPath = (self.superview! as! UITableView).indexPath(for: self)! as NSIndexPath
```

It works fine on iOS 11 simulator, but on the iOS 10 device, it gives this error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewWrapperView'  to 'UITableView'
```

What can I do to get it working on both iOS 10 and 11?

Comment: 1. Never make any assumptions about a cell's or table's private subview structure. It seems to change every iOS update. 2. Why does a cell need to know its own indexPath? That's a bad design.

Comment: Why don't you just store a weak reference to your parent `UITableView` in your custom cell and then call `indexPath(for:self)` on it? For example `let indexPath = self.parentTableView.indexPath(for: self)!`

Comment: @rmaddy didn't know it was a bad design, I have a table of members and a button in each cell that needs cell index to perform its action based on member's id.

Comment: @ Robotic Cat, That actually did the trick! I created a weak var parentTable in the cell class, and then passed it the tableView from cellForRow method like cell.parentTableView = self.membersTableView. I hope you can make your comment as an answer to accept it, thank you.

Comment: @RoboticCat A cell has no need to know its own table view. Such a design is a bad idea.

Comment: @rmaddy, so what is your suggestion to perform an action for a button in a cell, where the action needs to know the indexPath?

Comment: Use the delegate pattern and have the cell call its delegate (the table view most likely) that some event needs to be handled. Without more specific information about what you actually are trying to accomplish, I can't provide a more specific suggestion.

Comment: yea the delegate pattern sounds a possible solution, I'll need to think how I'll  go about doing it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a bad design to get index path inside a custom cell.You can check on which version you are running and implement the logic to get indexPath.

```
// INDEXPATH VARIABLE
var indexPath :NSIndexPath!

// CHECK FOR IOS 11 AND ABOVE
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
 // CALCULATE USING TABLE VIEW
 indexPath = (self.superview! as! UITableView).indexPath(for: self)! as NSIndexPath
} else {
  // CALCULATE USING TABLEVIEW WRAPPER
  indexPath = (self.superview!.superview as! UITableView).indexPath(for: self)! as NSIndexPath
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you that was a good idea, but as rmaddy mentioned that it could change depending on the iOS version. Robotic Cat suggested a correct solution.

Comment: Do not use this code. There are far better ways to get the cell's table view. But more importantly, this should even be done. There is no reason a cell needs to know its table view or its indexPath.